# jQuery Slideshow that supports more than 1 image per slide?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery slideshow plugin which will allow more than 1 image per slide. I need to place 4 different images into one slide and have them rotate. Unfortunately most sliders I've viewed doesn't seem to allow more than 1 image. Does anyone know of a slideshow plugin that does this.

Comment: Sorry, have to vote to close this because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." That said, see http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/infinitecarousel3/demo/d2.html

Comment: Yep.  You need a carousel, not a slideshow: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Comment: Yeah. Should of just asked a question regarding the plugin I was using.

Comment: Thank you for the carousel suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

You can take a look at some of the examples or the documentation to get a better idea of it's capabilities. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Nivoslider](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/) with out having any issues.